# Need of awk command explaination

Tags: unix, awk

I want to know how the below command is working.

```
awk '/Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value/ {block=1} block {str=str sep $0; sep=RS} /^==.*== $/ {block=0; if (str!~/oracle/ && str!~/OCI/ && str!~/tuxedo1222/ &&  str!~/vprintf/ && str!~/vfprintf/ && str!~/vtrace/) { if (str!~/^$/){print str}} str=sep=""}' file_name.txt >> CondJump_val.txt
```

I'd also like to know how to check the texts Oracle, OCI, and so on from the second line only.

Comment: You should include a reference to wherever you got that command from so we have context on what it's supposed to do. Or even better provide sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to write it so it's easier to read

```bash
awk '
    /Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value/ {block=1}
    block {
        str=str sep $0
        sep=RS
    }
    /^==.*== $/ {
        block=0
        if (str!~/oracle/ && str!~/OCI/ && str!~/tuxedo1222/ &&  str!~/vprintf/ && str!~/vfprintf/ && str!~/vtrace/) {
            if (str!~/^$/) {
                print str
            }
        }
        str=sep=""
    }
' file_name.txt >> CondJump_val.txt
```

It accumulates the lines starting with "Conditional jump ..." ending with "==...== " into a variable str.
If the accumulated string does not match several patterns, the string is printed.

> I'd also like to know how to check the texts Oracle, OCI, and so on from the second line only.

What does that mean? I assume you don't want to see the "Conditional jump..." line in the output. If that's the case then use the `next` command to jump to the next line of input.

```
    /Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value/ {
        block=1
        next
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I still don't understand the use of block and its values such as 0 and 1, as well as the use of str=sep="" .  
Also I want to apply below condition on second line after matching the first line "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value". 
Next Condition after first line match ==> str!~/oracle/ && str!~/OCI/ && str!~/tuxedo1222/ &&  str!~/vprintf/ && str!~/vfprintf/ && str!~/vtrace/

Answer (score 0):

perhaps consolidate those `regex` into a single chain ?

> ```
> if (str !~ "oracle|OCI|tuxedo1222|v[f]?printf|vtrace") {
>
>     print str
> }
> ```

Comment: Maybe `if (str != "" && str !~ /.../)` to include the `str!~/^$/` check

Comment: @glennjackman : then might as well also pad that into the `regex` :::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::::::: : `if (str !~ /^$|………/) { print str }`

Answer (score 0):

There are two idiomatic awkisms to understand.

The first can be simplified to this:

```
$ seq 100 | awk '/^22$/{flag=1} 
/^31$/{flag=0} 
flag' 
22
23
...
30
```

Why does this work? In awk, `flag` can be tested even if not yet defined which is what the stand alone `flag` is doing - the input is only printed if `flag` is true and `flag=1` is only executed when after the regex `/^22$/`. The condition of `flag` being true ends with the regex `/^31$/` in this simple example.

This is an idiom in `awk` to executed code between two regex matches on different lines.

In your case, the two regex's are:

```
/Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value/  # start
# in-between, block is true and collect the input into str separated by RS
/^==.*== $/   # end
```

The other 'awkism' is this:

```
block {str=str sep $0; sep=RS}
```

When `block` is true, collect `$0` into `str` and first time though, `RS` should not be added in-between the last time. The result is:

```
str="first lineRSsecond lineRSthird lineRS..."
```

both depend on awk being able to use a undefined variable without error